# How to dynamically change JAVA_HOME from /usr/libexec/java_home in Mac

Tags: java, macos, shell, java-home

I have jdk1.8 installed on my system in `Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_171.jdk`
but for some reasons I want to **temporarily** use jdk9  present in Documents folder using a script.

To be precise: `/Users/divyanshukumar/documents/jdk1.9.jdk/Contents/Home/`

I used following two export in the script to change java home:

1. `export JAVA_HOME=/Users/divyanshukumar/documents/jdk1.9.jdk/Contents/Home/`
2. `export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH`

This results are good if check by `which java`
But the output of `/usr/libexec/java_home` still points to the jdk1.8 installed on my system, how should I change the output of this command too.

Also I want this to happen only temporarily, i.e. only in one session of Terminal, or while execution of this script only.

Please do suggest how to achieve this, also key points to be remember are:

1. I don't want to move this jdk to JavaVirtualMachine Folder i.e. use it as is location.
2. The changes should be temporary, i.e. after one exits from the script, every thing should be back as they were.
3. I want the solution for MacOS and not Linux/Windows.